# BIOS INT 0x13 function 8

Tags: usb, hpc, real-mode

Im' trying to get USB drive parameters using BIOS interrupt 0x13 function 8 in x86 real mode. I need the number of heads per track (HPC parameter). What values do I pass to registers and in which registers are the results stored? Are there any additional bitwise calculation to be done to get HPC value from returned result?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_13H#List_of_INT_13h_services ?